# I'm looking for a reason for a type error after a successful request from the reducer

Tags: reactjs

I don't know why I got an error on the reducer

[image]

reducer code

```
        case ADD_COMMENT_SUCCESS: {
            const postIndex = state.mainPosts.findIndex(v => v.id === action.data.postId);
            const post = state.mainPosts[postIndex];
            const Comments = [...post.Comments, action.data.comment];
            const mainPosts = [...state.mainPosts];
            mainPosts[postIndex] = { ...post, Comments };
            return {
                ...state,
                isAddingComment: false,
                mainPosts,
                commentAdded: true,
            };
        }
```

error is occured in this

```
const Comments = [...post.Comments, action.data.comment];
```

git:
https://github.com/hyunsokstar/node_bird_33

https://github.com/hyunsokstar/node_bird_33/blob/master/front/reducers/post.js

https://github.com/hyunsokstar/node_bird_33/blob/master/front/components/PostCard.js

thanks for let me know how to fix it

Comment: Please check `post.Comments`, if it's not an array, the exception will be thrown.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is because the `findIndex` returns you `undefined` for case when the `id`s are not matched, and which leads to something like `undefined.Comments` which throws you error.

```
        case ADD_COMMENT_SUCCESS: {
            const postIndex = state.mainPosts.findIndex(v => v.id === action.data.postId);
            if(postIndex){
               const post = state.mainPosts[postIndex];
               const Comments = [...post.Comments, action.data.comment];
               const mainPosts = [...state.mainPosts];
                mainPosts[postIndex] = { ...post, Comments };
                return {
                  ...state,
                  isAddingComment: false,
                  mainPosts,
                  commentAdded: true,
                };
             }
              else{
              // Write Your logic if the index is not found
              return state;

        }
```